# SQL percent query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that I wont to query some data from. The problem is that the query never stops and never gives any result.

The task is to get the percent of all male actors.

```
filmparticipation(partid, personid, filmid, parttype)

person(personid, lastname, firstname, gender)
```

Her is my try, can someone please give me a hint to achive the task?

```
SELECT (COUNT(p.personid) / COUNT(a.person)) * 100
FROM person p, person a, filmparticipation f
WHERE
f.parttype = 'cast' AND
p.gender = 'M';
```

Answer (score 5):

You had no `ON` clauses for your joins, so you were joining every record with every other record across three tables! Instead, try something like this:

```
select (count(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) / count(*)) * 100
from person p
inner join filmparticipation f on p.personid = f.personid
where f.parttype = 'cast'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT (COUNT(p.personid) / subq.total) * 100
FROM person p, (select count(personID) as total from person) subq, filmparticipation f
WHERE
f.parttype = 'cast' 
and f.personid = p.personid    
and p.gender = 'M';
```

I *think* the problem you had before was you selected from `person` twice and did not join the second selection (`a`) with anything, possibly leading to a cartesian join (which would return eventually, but maybe not for while).

Comment: you still need a join between person and filmparticipation

Comment: Agreed with Conrad; the missing join is arguably the most-important part of the problem. :)

Comment: @Conrad: Fixed. I just copied the original query and fixed the most obvious (to me, that is) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of the problem is you're not joining the tables - you're not giving the query any relationship between them, and so it's attempting to aggregate all possible combinations of all records in all the tables. You want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.personid) AS ActorCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MaleActorCount, 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(p.personid) * 100) AS PercentMaleActors
FROM person p
INNER JOIN filmparticipation f ON p.personid = f.personid
WHERE f.parttype = 'cast'
```